# Getting systemctl service status

Tags: shell, unix, systemctl

I am trying to get the status of systemctl service using below command.

`systemctl --no-pager status service_name | grep "Active" | cut -d ":" -f2`

The output i am getting is

`active (exited) since Mon 2023-09-04 21`

I just want active or inactive in the output. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: `systemctl status service_name` return code `0` for active,  `> 0` for inactive

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl is-active service_name
```

What this command does is check whether any of the specified units are active (i.e. running). Returns an exit code 0 if at least one is active, or non-zero otherwise. You can find it int the man manual